# Why there is no temporary object when returning an object through the constructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, temporary-objects, copy-elision

I'm trying to figure out what exactly happens when returning an object through the constructor(conversion function).

```
Stonewt::Stonewt(const Stonewt & obj1) {
    cout << "Copy constructor shows up." << endl;
}

Stonewt::Stonewt(double lbs) {
    cout << "Construct object in lbs." << endl;
}

Stonewt::~Stonewt() {
    cout << "Deconstruct object." << endl;
}

Stonewt operator-(const Stonewt & obj1, const Stonewt & obj2) {
    double pounds_tmp = obj1.pounds - obj2.pounds;
    return Stonewt(pounds_tmp);
}

int main() {
    Stonewt incognito = 275;
    Stonewt wolfe(285.7);

    incognito = wolfe - incognito;
    cout << incognito << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Output:
Construct object in lbs.
Construct object in lbs.

Construct object in lbs.
Deconstruct object.
10.7 pounds

Deconstruct object.
Deconstruct object.
```

So My Question is:

Why there is no copy constructor (no temporary object) when returning an object through the constructor?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you just not understand what a destructor is? You have too much code here to expect a decent answer as-is.

Comment: @RyanHaining I re-edited it just now.

Comment: I think you're looking for [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: @RyanHaining That's it. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Stonewt operator-(const Stonewt & obj1, const Stonewt & obj2)
{
    ...
    return obj1;
}
```

```
   incognito = incognito - wolfe;
```

Your `operator - ()` is returning a copy of `incognito`, which you then assign to `incognito`.  The copy is then destroyed.

Comment: I thought the temporary object was created by the defaul constructor, so I added "cout << "Construct object with defaul constructor." << endl;" in the defalt constructor function. But there still no information about the constructor in the output. So which constructor it uses to create the temporary object? Thank you~

Comment: @LeoHu, that's because the default copy constructor is used.  Implement a copy constructor, and it will be called.